# Take one object from many of the same object in array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have array of object like this :

```
var myArr = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "john"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "frank"},
    {"id": 1, "name": "john"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "andrey"}
];
```

if there is the same object then shown one, like this :

```
var myArr = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "john"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "frank"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "andrey"}
];
```

anyone please help me.
thanks.

Comment: What would be a formal definition for the "same"?

Comment: in array myArr contained in the same object, namely {"id": 1, "name": "john"}, if there is the same object then it is only shown once.

Comment: "same object" in JS is not what you think. In your examples all those are independent different objects. That's why I asked you to formalise it. But anyway, in the duplicates everything is explained clearly.